# Use Search Term in html link and redirect

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, html

i want to make a redirect with the search from users term/query from the user. the term should be after the `s=` and before the `&post_type=post`

thanks for help

this is my code but i get critical error on wordpress:

`<p class="woocommerce-info"><?php wp_redirect( "https://mypagenamehere.de/product-search/?s="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>"&post_type=post" ); ?></p>`

Comment: Redirects have to happen before page output, so yes, this will cause issues. Are you trying to redirect someone visiting this page before they even see the content, or are you instead trying to set up a link that they can click on after they view the page?

Comment: i try to redirect just if search results are zero. this is the woocommerce no-results.php. it works allready i just need to get the search query from the user after the "/?s="                    to complete the link

Comment: What critical error are you getting?